# Neo4j cypher: Limiting returned results by an expression

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to limit my results to a randomized set. So far, I have this query working:

```
MATCH (n),
RETURN n, rand() as random
ORDER BY random
LIMIT 25
```

However, when trying to replace `LIMIT 25` with a random number, things go wrong, in both of the following two cypher examples:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n, rand() as random, toInt(rand()*25) as randCount
ORDER BY random
LIMIT randCount
```

*In the above, removing LIMIT returns randcount correctly*

```
WITH toInt(rand()*25) as randCount
MATCH (n)
RETURN n, rand() as random
ORDER BY random
LIMIT randCount
```

My immediate thought is that Cypher doesn't (yet) support using a variable/expression to limit results... Or I'm doing it wrong ;-)

Comment: This is something that's scheduled for development but not done yet :)

Comment: Sounds great @MichaelHunger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your examples and you're right, cypher doesn't support variable as argument for `LIMIT`.

Here is the proof you're looking for:

I started the above query:

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n)
RETURN n, rand() as random, toInt(rand()*25) as randCount
ORDER BY random
LIMIT 1
```

Here is the result:

[image: PROFILE Result]

As you can see on the profile result, `LIMIT` is executed before randCount is affected, so when you do `LIMIT randCount`randCount doesn't exist, like every other variables you created.

Even if random is done in the Projection part, its value is not affected to randCount immediately.